# Random boolean 2d-array in Java returning always "false"

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

I just wanted to create a random boolean 2d-array but it always returns false...A problem with the operator "&&"? I don't get it...

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    boolean[][] arr = new boolean[5][5];
    Random r = new Random();
    boolean row = r.nextBoolean();
    boolean col = r.nextBoolean();

    for(int i=0 ; i<arr.length ; i++){

        for(int j=0;j<arr[i].length;j++){

        arr[i][j] = row && col;

        System.out.print(arr[i][j]+"\t");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think all you want is to create a new random boolean for each cell in the array like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    boolean[][] arr = new boolean[5][5];
    Random r = new Random();

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++){

            arr[i][j] = r.nextBoolean();

            System.out.print(arr[i][j]+"\t");
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Happy to help! Can you mark my answer as correct please?

Answer (score 3):

You only calculate row and col once, try this instead:

```
boolean[][] arr = new boolean[5][5];
Random r = new Random();
boolean row;
boolean col;

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
        row = r.nextBoolean();
        col = r.nextBoolean();
        arr[i][j] = row && col;
        System.out.print(arr[i][j] + "\t");
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if there is any point in making separate `row` and `col`, and then taking an `&&` of them. All it does is reducing the number of `true` elements by about a factor of two.

Comment: @khelwood Right, two, not four!

Comment: I think maybe he wants to get something out of it later, why else should he have two randoms? Ah, i think i now know, what exactly he wants. But that should be another answer.

Comment: It's hard to tell what the OP wanted to do. My only guess is that he may have wanted to have the same `boolean`s in each row and in each column, e.g. `boolean[] row = new boolean[5]; boolean[] col = new boolean[5];` set them to random values, then use `arr[i][j] = row[i] && col[j]`.

Comment: That was just my thought hence the second answer

Answer (score 1):

After thinking of what you might want, this seems more plausible: 
For every row a boolean and for every column a boolean, giving this:

```
int columns =5;
int rows =5;
boolean[][] arr = new boolean[rows][columns];
Random r = new Random();
boolean[] row = new boolean[rows];
boolean[] col = new boolean[columns];

for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
    row[i] = r.nextBoolean();
}
for(int i=0; i<columns; i++){
    col[i] = r.nextBoolean();
}

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
        arr[i][j] = row[i] && col[j];
        System.out.print(arr[i][j] + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is compiled and working JAVA solution


/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        boolean[][] arr = new boolean[5][5];
        int cnt = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < arr[i].length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++)
            {
                Random r = new Random();
                boolean row = r.nextBoolean();
                boolean col = r.nextBoolean();
                arr[i][j] = row && col;
                System.out.print(arr[i][j]+"\t");
            }
        }
}
```